# How to create button at EE and run powershell script

Tags: experience-editor, powershell-extensions

I need to add a custom button for EE and run a script if the user clicks on the button.
basically, I know how to create a button at the core database at

```
/sitecore/content/Applications/WebEdit/Ribbons/WebEdit
```

and I know that I need call command like `item:executescript(id=$Target,script={93BAF91E-1111-4C90-8A1F-5AF71C9B7033},scriptDb=master)`
but I am not sure that should be set at layout option for this button at Sitecore Rock,

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this? I've tried a few things, but it seems like the EE ribbon may need a backend task with Speak and JS. So far PowerShell scripts only seem to run via content editor ribbons, but Im hoping somebody else had better luck.

Answer (score 1):

If you are doing a button on Experience editor ribbon, you should add the button in the core database.

e.g, We have added a button called Unlock Item - which unlocks the locked items of other users

Steps we followed to do this:

1. Added a button in core DB under content --> Applications --> Content Editor --> Ribbons --> Chunks --> Workflow Edit
2. Set the click event like 'contenteditorcustom:unlockitem'
3. Created a Custom Command and implemented the logic in Execute method (in your case executing PowerShell script)
4. Added a patch config for the command under commands with name 'contenteditorcustom:unlockitem' and set the type to the Custom command class.

This should enable the Experience editor button to function the way you want.

Hope this helps

Comment: These instructions should work for the content editor, but not in the Experience editor. So far I have not found a way to use PowerShell in EE ribbon buttons.

Comment: This will not work in experience editor.